# Volunteering for certain harm

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

During the [Fukushima nuclear disaster](http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/asiapcf/05/31/japan.nuclear.suicide/index.html?hpt=hp_t2) elderly people volunteered to work in high radiation environments to fix the problem, because they felt less concerned about dying. Either they were more comfortable with the idea, or they might get sick anyway, or the effects would be less pronounced on older people, and similar reasons.

Of course the underlying motivation was to save lives.

What would be the Halachic view of volunteering like that?

Comment: I am lacking sources, but I once heard in a shiur that it's a 3-way machlokes rishonim about entering a makom of vadai sakana for pikuach nefesh of others: obligated, optional, and not allowed. Will try to find sources.

Comment: I'm going to try to go to [this conference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8pV_AB_KYvpc2l6Q3RhUXk4OW9GNmI0WDBrTjY5eXlaQldV/view) if I can; it should have bearing on your question.

Answer (score 3):

The Netziv writes in The Ha'amek Davar, about people going home from the battle due to their fears, that in fact suicidal people were allowed to go to the battlefield in order to end their lives in a productive way.